# Auto Layout with UIImageView is producing incorrect view layout when an image is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I have an UIImageView in my app and it resizes perfectly according to the constraints that I set to it. But when I load an image into the UIImageView, it messes up everything. What could be causing the problem?

Here are some screenshots attached:

(The blue square is the ImageView)

***As you can see, there is a UITextView above the UIImageView which should be visible like here:***

[image]

***But, when an image is loaded into the UIImageView, it stretches into a square for some weird reason, hiding the UITextView above it..***

[image]

**EDIT:**

*My constraints attached to the UIImageView*
[image]

Comment: What constraints do you have on the image view?

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot of the constraints.

Comment: Are you also setting the text view's text? Setting the text to `nil` or `@""` would cause your issue if you don't have a height constraint on the label.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case :(

Comment: how are you loading hte image? from storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: I load it programatically but I also tried assigning one from the storyboard..made no difference. Also, checking "Clip subviews" did not help

Comment: Make UIimageView superview of Text view ... you are covering the Uiimageview with textview

Comment: I am afraid that did not help either. :((

Comment: I see a yellow warning icon in your screenshot. Are the warnings related to your constraints? Also, we'd need to see all of your constraints to know what's going on. What are the constraints on the text field and on the view above it?

Comment: Also, are you intentionally using size classes? If so, when you run, does the device orientation match up with the size class where you are setting the constraints (compact width regular height)?

Comment: Maybe try changing the contentMode of your UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

use this

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;